# Symfony2 - invalidate session when user clicks back

Tags: php, symfony

Using Symfony2, is there a secure way to invalidate the current user session if the user clicks the browser back button?

Comment: Is this to prevent a user hitting the back button to return to a secure section of the site?

Comment: Not quite - rather it should prevent the user from clicking the back button in any secure context. I know that seeking to control the clients browser in this way is most likely a generally smelly thing to do, but the current design requires it.

Answer (score 0):

You can define allowed tranision steps for user browser and check it at every controller call storing data with session

for example you define that transition from A to B (i.e. cart viewing to cart checkout in e-shop) is allowed, so you check, that current state is B and previous session state is A, than update session state. If controller realizes, that transition is not allowed - you can form an exception or do any other things (i.e. invalidate security token).

But you need to implement transition map in this way.

Actually, you have no way to **prevent** clicking. This is made at the client side. All you can do - just properly respond to this action.